# Запуск Qt программы на сервере с ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5

Есть сервер ubuntu 14.04. Вывод команды `uname -a`:

```
Linux **** 2.6.32-042stab120.20 #1 SMP Fri Mar 10 16:52:50 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Собрал Qt 5.8.0 x64 статически, с помощью него собрал программу (пока - простейший hello world, но с использованием Qt). При запуске на сервере получаю:

```
bash: ./Temp_qt: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Почему так происходит? Вроде ведь разрядность совпадает. Ещё есть предположение что поможет эта инфа: вывод команды `file ./Temp_qt`

```
./Temp_qt: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), too many program header sections (3328)
```

P.S. Проблема решена! Дело было в кривой передачи файла на сервер (передача шла по ftp в ASCII режиме). Выяснилось это по выходу команды `readelf -a <file>`.

Comment: 1- сообщение об ошибке ("cannot execute binary file: Exec format error") можно прямо в заголовок вопроса добавить (чтобы людям в гугле с похожей проблемой легче ссылку найти) 2- Не помещайте решение (ответ) в сам вопрос, опубликуйте свой ответ вместо этого -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs
>Для публикации ответа на свой вопрос необходимо иметь 15 баллов репутации.